# Pokemon: Gameboy to 3DS trading?

Tags: pokemon-series

Essentially want I want to do is trade from Pokemon Red/Gold and with Pokemon x. Is there any cord/equipment (specifically) out there that allows me to trade Pokemon from games playable on my Gameboy Advance SP with games on my 3DS?

I also have a DS floating around (and Platinum game) somewhere that I could use as a middle-man, but I'd rather not if possible.

Any technique to do this would be great.

Comment: It's a long and complicated process. Are you sure you want to go all the way from Red/Gold? If that's even possible, I'm not sure if you could transfer from 2nd gen to 3rd. It's been too long.

Answer (score 3):

All Pokemon on the Gameboy games are trapped there, as there is no way to get trades from Red/Blue/Yellow/Green/Gold/Silver/Crystal to FireRed/LeafGreen and Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald. You can however, move Pokemon from FireRed/LeafGreen and Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald to Diamond/Pearl/Platinum and HeartGold/SoulSilver, and then transfer Pokemon from those to Black/White and Black2/White2. Soon, Nintendo will release a way to move Pokemon from 5th Gen to 6th, but it is not released yet.

In summary, there is no way to get Pokemon from Pokemon Red/Blue and other 1st and 2nd Gen games to any future installments.

EDIT:
With the release of the Pokebank, you can move Pokemon from the DS games to the 3DS games with ease. It does require paying a yearly subscription for the Pokebank, but it is relatively cheap, only being 5 USD a year.